# Modify Active Directory Client OU from Client Machine

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to create a powershell startup script for my domain controlled computers that will place the computer into the the specified OU. I would like for the variables to be taken on the local computer and then passed to the remote server. Once there I would like to execute the last two lines on the server.

The script below does work if it is ran on the server however as stated above I would like to be able to execute this from a client machine. How can I make this happen?

```
$computername = $env:ComputerName
$new_ou = "OU=TestOU,DC=Test,DC=Controller,DC=com"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer $computername | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $new_ou
```

Note: Before anyone asks...my goal is to have the OU be determined by the client IP address. I understand that there are scripts that will do the discribed above but they run strictly on the server and query the DNS. I would rather have this run as a startup script on the local computer so I an better control which computers are being moved. At this point I am not interested in tackling this issue. Only the issue of how to execute the above lines on a local machine.

Comment: Did you try running the script from a client (while logged on the client)? I guess you will need the AD module from RSAT enabled. You could also have the machine run a script to drop a file on the server with its IP address (and more if needed) and run a script on the server to do the AD work as a scheduled task. You could also link IP subnets to Active Directory sites iirc.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to run the last 2 lines on the server because you expect that most of your domain computers won't have the RSAT tools or AD cmdlets installed.

The way to run it on a server is to have PowerShell Remoting enabled on the server and then use `Invoke-Command`.

That authentication is typically done with kerberos, though you could change the method, and you can supply credentials manually (though I doubt you want to be embedding credentials in the script).

You need to consider that the user making the AD changes needs permission to do so. Usually that's a domain admin, although permission could be delegated.

If you're running this as a startup script, it's running as `SYSTEM`. That account authenticates on the domain as the computer account (`COMPUTERNAME$`). This means that the computer account needs permission to move itself, which may mean it needs the ability to write objects into all possible OUs (I don't recall offhand which permissions are needed).

So you would either need to grant this ability to all computers (any computer in `Domain Computers` would have the ability to move any other computer to any OU), or somehow give each computer only the ability to move itself into the correct OU (which might still be too much in the way of permissions).

Another option is to make a customized session configuration on the server with a RunAs user. You could limit the users allowed to connect to the session (to `Domain Computers`), and limit the allowed commands so that the connecting computers can only run a limited set of functions/cmdlets. Even better, you can write your own function to do the change and only let them run that one. With the RunAs user being a privileged user in AD, the changes will work without the connecting user having the ability to make the changes directly, and without giving the connecting user the ability to use the privileged user or elevate their own permission. Remember that the connecting user in this case is the computer account.

This last method is, I think, the best/most secure way to do what you want, if you insist that it must be initiated from the client machine.

Reconsider doing this as a server-side process. `Get-ADComputer` can return an IPv4 address for the object, so you could use that instead of DNS. Centralizing it would make it easier to manage and troubleshoot the process.

Comment: So I did a bit more thinking about what you said and I believe you are right. It is easlier and more secure to organize via the server. I did a bit of research and I am basing my script off of the floowing: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/03/use-powershell-to-move-computers-based-on-ip-addresses.aspx

Comment: I think the concept seemed simple but as I got into building it out I began to see something that I was a bit uneasy with. For me the particularly difficult and concerning thing was what you mentioned in the 5th paragraph.

Comment: @thebradnet nice! The only thing I might mention is that the article you linked to is a bit long in the tooth. It uses the Quest AD cmdlets but by now you could just use Microsoft's `ActiveDirectory` module.

Comment: @thebradnet yeah that was the crux of it for me too. Even if you could lock down the AD permissions in such a way, it seems like something that would need to be exceptionally well-documented, and might need constant work (every new computer added separately, every decommissioned computer removed separately). Constrained endpoints really offer some nice options, it just seems like this particular task can be done centrally with less effort and better results.

Comment: you are right, I did link to one that uses Quest. The same fellow who wrote that article has a version of the same script that used the ActiveDirectory module. I believe it is linked on the same page.